# HomeScreen Widget in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, mobile, widget

I was trying to add a HomeScreen widget using Kotlin in Flutter using the `es.antonborri.home_widget.HomeWidgetProvider`

[image]

It has 3 buttons on the top and a ListView, When the button is clicked, the List has to update with new data.

The WidgetProvider code is as below.

```
package com.sampleapp.widget

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View;
import android.util.Log

import es.antonborri.home_widget.HomeWidgetProvider;

import com.sampleapp.MainActivity;
import com.sampleapp.R;

class WidgetProvider : HomeWidgetProvider() {
    companion object {
        const val ITEM_CTA = R.string.item_cta_key
        const val ACTION_CLICKED = R.string.action_clicked
        const val ACTION_RESTOCK_CLICKED = R.string.action_restock_clicked
        const val ACTION_EMPTY_CLICKED = R.string.action_empty_clicked
        const val ACTION_LOW_CLICKED = R.string.action_low_clicked
    }

    private var restockButtonClicked = true
    private var emptyButtonClicked = false
    private var lowButtonClicked = false

    override fun onEnabled(context: Context?) {
        super.onEnabled(context)
    }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent?) {
        val appWidgetId: Int = intent?.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) ?: AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID

        if (intent?.action == context.getString(ACTION_RESTOCK_CLICKED)) {
            restockButtonClicked = true
            emptyButtonClicked = false
            lowButtonClicked = false
            val appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)
            appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetId, R.id.items)
        } else if (intent?.action == context.getString(ACTION_EMPTY_CLICKED)) {
            restockButtonClicked = false
            emptyButtonClicked = true
            lowButtonClicked = false
            val appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)
            appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetId, R.id.items)
        } else if (intent?.action == context.getString(ACTION_LOW_CLICKED)) {
            restockButtonClicked = false
            emptyButtonClicked = false
            lowButtonClicked = true
            val appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)
            appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetId, R.id.items)
        } else if (intent?.action == context?.getString(ACTION_CLICKED)) {
            val cta: String? = intent?.getStringExtra(context?.getString(ITEM_CTA))
            val launchIntent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
            launchIntent.setAction(context.getString(R.string.app_widget_launch_action))
            launchIntent.setData(Uri.parse(context.getString(R.string.app_widget_card_clicked_uri) + "/" + cta))
            launchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            context.startActivity(launchIntent)
        }
        super.onReceive(context, intent)
    }

    override fun onUpdate(
        context: Context,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetIds: IntArray,
        widgetData: SharedPreferences
    ) {
        for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
            val views = RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.app_widget_layout)
            val widgetRestockData = widgetData.getString(context.getString(R.string.widget_restock_data), "")
            val widgetLowData = widgetData.getString(context.getString(R.string.widget_low_data), "")
            val widgetEmptyData = widgetData.getString(context.getString(R.string.widget_empty_data), "")

            val restockIntent = Intent(context, WidgetService::class.java)
            restockIntent.setAction(context.getString(ACTION_RESTOCK_CLICKED))
            restockIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId)
            restockIntent.setData(Uri.parse(restockIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)))
            restockIntent.putExtra(context.getString(R.string.widget_item_data), widgetRestockData)

            val restockButtonPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                0,
                restockIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
            )
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.restockButton, restockButtonPendingIntent)

            val emptyIntent = Intent(context, WidgetService::class.java)
            emptyIntent.setAction(context.getString(ACTION_EMPTY_CLICKED))
            emptyIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId)
            emptyIntent.setData(Uri.parse(emptyIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)))
            emptyIntent.putExtra(context.getString(R.string.widget_item_data), widgetEmptyData)

            val emptyButtonPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                0,
                emptyIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
            )
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.emptyButton, emptyButtonPendingIntent)

            val lowIntent = Intent(context, WidgetService::class.java)
            lowIntent.setAction(context.getString(ACTION_LOW_CLICKED))
            lowIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId)
            lowIntent.setData(Uri.parse(lowIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)))
            lowIntent.putExtra(context.getString(R.string.widget_item_data), widgetLowData)

            val lowButtonPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                0,
                lowIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
            )
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.lowButton, lowButtonPendingIntent)

            val clickIntent = Intent(context, WidgetProvider::class.java)
            clickIntent.setAction(context.getString(ACTION_CLICKED))
            clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId)
            clickIntent.setData(Uri.parse(clickIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)))

            val clickPendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                0,
                clickIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
            )

            if (emptyButtonClicked) {
                if (widgetEmptyData.isNullOrEmpty() || widgetEmptyData == "[]") {
                    views.setTextViewText(R.id.emptyItemsMessage, "There are no empty items.")
                    views.setViewVisibility(R.id.emptyItemsMessage, View.VISIBLE)
                }
                views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.items, emptyIntent)

            } else if (lowButtonClicked) {
                if (widgetLowData.isNullOrEmpty() || widgetLowData == "[]") {
                    views.setTextViewText(R.id.emptyItemsMessage, "There are no items with low quantity")
                    views.setViewVisibility(R.id.emptyItemsMessage, View.VISIBLE)
                }
                views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.items, lowIntent)
            } else {
                if (widgetRestockData.isNullOrEmpty() || widgetRestockData == "[]") {
                    views.setTextViewText(R.id.emptyItemsMessage, "There are no items to restock.")
                    views.setViewVisibility(R.id.emptyItemsMessage, View.VISIBLE)
                }
                views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.items, restockIntent)
            }

            views.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.items, clickPendingIntent)
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
        }
    }
}
```

The button click is not working and the List is not updating. What am I doing wrong, happy to provide more info as possible.
Appreciate any help.